# Eliminate fadeIn blink

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a rather standard technique for fading in `<body>` with jQuery while keeping it visible for those users who don't have JavaScript enabled.

In CSS, I set

```css
body.has-js {
    display:none;
}
```

Then I add `.has-js` with the following jQuery snippet in the `<head>` section:

```html
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $("body").addClass("has-js");
   });

   window.onload = function() {
      jQuery("body").fadeIn(500);
   }
</script>
```

The desired result is to make the website initially invisible and then have it fade in smoothly once all the content has loaded.

**Problem:** apparently, content loads before JavaScript kicks in, so the page flickers briefly before .has-js class is added. This happens in all browsers except Firefox.

**Question:** how can I eliminate that flicker, while still keeping the site visible to those users who have JavaScript disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting this just after your opening `<body>`:

```
<script>
(function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    var body = elements[0];
    body.className = "has-js";
})();
</script>
```

You don't really need to wait for the DOM to load in your scenario, and whenever this script will be loaded you have a guarantee that at least the `body` element is available.

In case your `body` already has a class assigned to it in HTML, replace the final line with the following:

```
body.className += " has-js";
```

Comment: I think it should put just after <body> tag, no?

Comment: @roasted: He could do that too, yes.

Comment: Im wondering if putting it in head will work. If yes, seems better then to put in <head>

Comment: Tried. In the <head>, the script doesn't work. After the body, the site blinks.

Comment: @Figaro: Yeah just checked that too, for some reason I thought that body is available to scripts in head.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using dom ready like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("body").addClass("has-js");
});
```

Do something like that :

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'has-js';
    </script>
    <!-- Your content -->
</body>
```

Like that, when the body tag is created, it had his class before adding the content.

Comment: Genius. Thank you, @Karl-Andre, this of course solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, @MMM, I just noticed the edit. Thanks. I have another question though. For some peculiar reason adding the class messes up the display of nav menu. Could you try clicking on ABOUT to see what I mean?

Comment: For some reason, the `a` inside the `li` have a `margin : -11px 10px 10px 10px`. Change it to `margin : 0 10px 10px` and it work.

Comment: How come it wasn't affecting the display before the script was added after the body tag? Also, could you please click on INVESTORS now to see why top margin was set to -11px?

Comment: Ok then, replace the margin -11px and add to `.main-navigation ul ul` a padding of 11px.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. This works! But could you tell me, why adding the script revealed the issue that did not manifest itself before?

Comment: If there was no class on body before, i couldnt tell... Welcome in the fabulous word of programmation.

Answer (score 2):

I think thats because, the script will add the has-js class to body when document is ready. So put `<script>$("body").addClass("has-js");</script>` just after `<body>` tag.